# How to solve this problem with creating a clock in java?

Tags: java, eclipse

Write a program that reads a time consisting of hours, minutes and seconds from standard input. The user may also specify
the clock format (12-hour clock with AM/PM or 24-hour clock). Be sure to provide sanity checks for the indicated values (e.g.
minutes are comprised between 0 and 59).

here is what i have until now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the hours: ");
    int hours = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the minutes: ");
    int minutes = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the seconds: ");
    int seconds = scanner.nextInt();
    if (seconds >= 0 && seconds <= 60) {
      minutes = minutes + 1;
      if (minutes >= 60) {
        hours = hours + 1;
        minutes = 00;
        if (hours >= 24) {
          hours = 00;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(seconds + ":" + minutes + ":" + hours);
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: What's your problem? This looks fine to me.

Comment: The problem is that there is something missing. 
@RoshanaPitigala
"Write a program that reads a time consisting of hours, minutes and seconds from standard input. The user may also specify the clock format (12-hour clock with AM/PM or 24-hour clock). Be sure to provide sanity checks for the indicated values (e.g. minutes are comprised between 0 and 59). "

This is the asked program.

Comment: Please give us some inputs and current outputs with expected outputs.

Comment: So you need to ask the user to input a 24hr vs 12 hr then use while loops to validate their input.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala for example, when user types in "60" , minutes should get +1 and seconds should get back to 00

Comment: @xTwisteDx didnt learn while loops yet .. :D

Comment: @user10466742 feel free to use an `if` statement in lieu of while loops, it will simply verify 1x instead of over and over again. Some professors allow you to get creative and push your limits, others want you to stick directly to course work.

Comment: No one is gonna get marked correct on this on lol.

Comment: why not ? @xTwisteDx

Comment: @user10466742 did anyone answer correctly?

Comment: @xTwisteDx well to be honest, everyone here helped a bit, i posted the final solution with parts of all your codes together :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about integer division `/` and remainder  `%`. For example:

```
int seconds = 150;
System.out.println("minutes: " + seconds / 60); // minutes: 2
System.out.println("seconds: " + seconds % 60); // seconds: 30
```

Try this code to find out how it works:

```
int seconds = 123;
int minutes = 120;
int hours = 23;
int days = 10;

minutes += seconds / 60;
seconds %= 60;
hours += minutes / 60;
minutes %= 60;
days += hours / 24;
hours %= 24;

System.out.format("%d days, %02d:%02d:%02d hours\n", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
System.exit(0);
```

This will print out all correct times:

```
11 days, 01:02:03 hours
```

I'll add some comments to your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the hours: ");
    int hours = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the minutes: ");
    int minutes = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the seconds: ");
    int seconds = scanner.nextInt();
    if (seconds >= 0 && seconds <= 60) {
      minutes = minutes + 1; // why do you increment minutes here?
      if (minutes >= 60) {
        hours = hours + 1; // if minutes is 120, then you'd have to add 2 hours
        minutes = 00; // if minutes is 61, then you should not set minutes to 0
        if (hours >= 24) {
          hours = 00; // same here
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(seconds + ":" + minutes + ":" + hours);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of your manual calculations if you use the `java.util.Calendar` class.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours); //24 hour format (10PM is 22)
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);

System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
        + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

---

Output

```
Enter the hours: 20
Enter the minutes: 120
Enter the seconds: 1276

22:21:16
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with. I left out some because this is obviously schoolwork and you need to learn. This will give you an idea of the logic that needs to take place.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What format 12hr or 24hr? [12,24]");
    int format - scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the hours: ");
    int hours = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the minutes: ");
    int minutes = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the seconds: ");
    int seconds = scanner.nextInt();

    if (format == 12)
    {
      //do this code
      if (hours > 12 || hours < 0)
      {
        //do this code
        //accept input until hours is less than or equal to 12
        System.out.print("Enter the hours: ");
        hours = scanner.nextInt();
      }
      if (minutes > 60 || minutes < 0)
      {
        //do this code
        //accept input until minutes is less than or equal to 60
      }
      if (seconds > 60 || seconds < 0)
      {
        //do this code
        //accept input until seconds is less than or equal to 60
      }
          System.out.println(seconds + ":" + minutes + ":" + hours);
    }

    if (format == 24)
    {
      //do this code
      if (hours > 24 || hours < 0)
      {
        //do this code
        //accept input until hours is less than or equal to 24
      }
      if (minutes > 60 || minutes < 0)
      {
        //do this code
        //accept input until minutes is less than or equal to 60
      }
      if (seconds > 60 || seconds < 0)
      {
        //do this code
        //accept input until seconds is less than or equal to 60
      }
          System.out.println(seconds + ":" + minutes + ":" + hours);
    }
```

Comment: You should *also* read about integer division and remainder (modulo).

Comment: I tried your code, and it works finde, but there is something missing: there is not 60th minute/ 60th second shown on a clock, 
for example: it goes from 59s back to 0s, but then minutes go up for 1, and so on. how could we add that option to the code?

Comment: Use an additional `if` statement to check if a variable is at `60` and `if` it is then add `++` to hours or minutes, then an additional line setting hours or minutes to `00`.

Comment: @user10466742 Did you read the 3 lines of code with `/` and `%` which is covering all that? Or were you just searching for a code to copy+paste? For that, StackOverflow is not the right place.

Comment: @steffen no worries, i tried all suggestions, i am still trying out to figure out a solution

Comment: @xTwisteDx i added :
    if (seconds == 60) {
   minutes = minutes ++ ;
}

but it still doesnt add 1 to minutes

Comment: Ok, one last try... `minutes += seconds / 60` and `seconds %= 60;`. No need for `if`, `while` loops, checks for `== 60` or anything else.

Comment: okay, i edited my code and used your codes in it, but im not familiar with += and %= ,so im going to do a little research on that, but thank you very much @steffen for the usefull knowledge !!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution so far, i guess..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What format 12hr or 24hr? [12,24]");
    int clockFormat = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter seconds: ");
    int seconds = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter minutes: ");
    int minutes = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter hours: ");
    int hours = scanner.nextInt();
    if (clockFormat == 12)
    {

      while (hours > 12 || hours < 0)
      {

        System.out.print("Enter the hours: ");
        hours = scanner.nextInt();
      }
    }
    minutes += seconds / 60;
    seconds %= 60;
    hours += minutes / 60;
    minutes %= 60;

    System.out.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);

    scanner.close();
}

}
```